# Eliminate Left Recursion

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, left-recursion

The part I want to modify:

```
B -> F | B A | A
```

What is the correct way to remove this left recursion?

I was thinking

```
 B -> F R | A R
 R -> A R | ε
```

But I've been told this is incorrect

Comment: Have you search the web for algorithms to remove left recursion. Have you been told why your solution is considered incorrect? By whom? What algorithm did you use to obtain your result? Were there other CF rules in addition to the ones you are showing ? That could matter.

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" pattern to eliminate the immediate left recursion would have been:

```
B  -> F B' | A B'
B' -> ε | A B'
```

I guess this is why you have been told your solution is not right.

Nevertheless the information that your solution is incorrect is incorrect.

Terms derivable from the original grammar fragment
`B -> F | B A | A` are of the form `(F|A)A*`.

The grammar fragment you constructed produces exactly the same language. Hence your solution is correct.

Comment: It seems that your answer is identical to that in the question, up to renaming of `B'` into `R`.  That can hardly justify a difference in correctness. But I too see it as a correct answer, provided the OP did not hide some context that might matter.